# "Бесполезные" функции

Tags: c#, математика

Недавно, исследовав библиотеку `Math`, нашёл такие функции -
`DivRem(), IEEERemainder()`.
Прочитав [описание](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/20.2.php) понял что функция `DivRem()` возвращает результат от деления, а `IEEERemainder` - остаток от деления. То есть они делают тоже самое что и операторы `/` и `%`.

---

В таком случае в чём смысл добавлять их в библиотеку `Math`, да ещё и с таким "не простым" названием?

---

П.Н.
Stack Overflow автоматически из тега `math` делает тег `математика` и мне пока не удалось это исправить.

Comment: Вообще это касается большинства ЯП.

Comment: Эти метки [объявлены на ru so синонимом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0/synonyms). Насчёт ответа на сам вопрос: подозреваю сделано для того, чтобы иметь возможность написать юнит-тест на метод и тем самым оформить его спецификацию. Но вообще неплохо бы дать ссылку на гитхаб этой библиотеки, ведь есть же?

Comment: @AK дак про это речь то наверное https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=netframework-4.8 Автор прочитал небось что остаток в параметре  и все, а то что частное в результате не читал. отсюда и глупые вопросы

Comment: @gregzakharov А зачем вам метод если можно это сделать гораздо проще без каких либо методов

Comment: @gregzakharov Я c# не много использовал вот и хочу понять принцип, зачем на меня гонять?

Comment: Я вот C# не знаю вообще, но это гуглится за минуту https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#floating-point-remainder в частности в чём разнице между % и IEEEReminder

Comment: @AlexeyTen даже и гуглить не надо, методы с таким названием в каждом втором языке есть.

Comment: Потому что без функции делить придется 2 раза, а с функцией все за раз вычисляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Прочитав описание понял что функция DivRem() возвращает результат от деления.

А теперь прочитайте вдумчиво еще раз:

> Вычисляет частное двух чисел и возвращает **остаток в выходном параметре**.

и

> Возвращаемое значение - Int32 **Частное от деления указанных чисел.**

вот и получится что

```
int a = 5, b = 4, d,r;
d = Math.DivRem(a, b, r);
```

дадут значения `d= 2, r = 1`

Такие функции есть во многих языках программирования, например, `DivMod()` в Delphi, python, `std::div` в С++, и т.д.

Далее вы пишите, что

> IEEERemainder - остаток от деления

Как же вы читали докумнетацию? Там ведь целых пара абзацев написано про то, что она в действительности возвращает:

> Число, равное x – (y*Q), где Q является частным x / y, округленным до ближайшего целого числа (если x / y находится на равном расстоянии от двух целых чисел, выбирается четное число).
>
>   Если значение x - ( y*Q) равно нулю, возвращается значение +0 при положительном x, или значение -0 при отрицательном x.

А следующий после данного описания пример начинается со слов:

> В следующем примере значение остальной части, возвращаемой методом IEEERemainder, **отличается от остатка, возвращаемой оператором остатка %.**

Comment: даже с учетом того, что ссылка приведена не на msdn а на metanit то там написано _"возвращает результат от деления a/b, а остаток помещается в параметр result"_, то есть все равно указано, что возвращает и частное и остаток.

Comment: я читал не документацию от создателей а то что я указал в вопросе

Comment: первый вариант вы правы но второго там не было